# css :checked don't work but is(":checked") in jquery is working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a modal working with checkbox, when I click my label I see that the checkbox is selected and jQuery is working fine (adding class to body) but css  `className:checked`  doesn't work so my content isn't visible.

```js
var checkbox = $('.modal-state').attr('id');

$('#' + checkbox).on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("body").addClass("modal-open");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("modal-open");
  }
});
```

```css
.modal-fade-screen {
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 99999999999;
}

.modal-state:checked+.modal-fade-screen {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  {% for p in page.collection %}
    <label for="{{ p.slug }}">
      <div class="modal-trigger">
        <a href="{{ p.route }}"></a>

        <img src="/speakers/{{ p.slug }}/{{p.slug}}.png" height="120px" >
        <h2>{{ p.title }}</h2>
      </div>
    </label>
    <input class="modal-state" id="{{ p.slug }}" type="checkbox" /> 
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="modal-fade-screen">
    <div class="modal-inner">
      <div class="modal-close" for="modal-1">X</div>
      <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: + means that the element is placed immediatly after another element. And your checkbox is before which makes no sense.

Comment: As far as I know, the CSS should only work for the last checkbox.

Comment: what is `.modal-open`? You add it as a class in JS, but it's not in your CSS

Comment: Your code in isolation works: https://jsfiddle.net/73weqmmw/. Note that the `+` selector only selects immediate siblings, so that may not be the behaviour you require.

Comment: @ Joe B  .modal-open i use for overflow: hidden so i didn't paste it.

Comment: You may want to try .modal-state:checked~.modal-fade-screen with a ~ instead of a +. I'm not sure if {% endfor %} is getting in the way.

Comment: Now I see that this is definitely the '+' problem but i don't know what i can use instead